# Maximum of a complex quadratic form

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $x,a\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and is symmetric. What is the maximum of the following real function
> \begin{align}
> f(x)&=\sum_i(a_ix_i^*+a_i^*x_i)-\sum_{ij}x_i(M_{ij}+M_{ij}^*)x_j\\&=(a^Tx^*+a^Hx)-x^H(M^H+M)x
> \end{align}
> where $()^*$ is the complex conjugate and $()^H$ Hermitian conjugate.

Is it sufficient to find the partial derivatives of $f(x)$ with respect to $\Re(x_j)$ and to $\Im(x_j)$ and make them vanish for all $j$?